# How to find files dynamically and copy them to a directory in linux

Tags: linux, find, cp

Trying to find these files and copy them to a directory (test_dir);

```
abc-1.0.zip
kncb-1.0.zip
jenk-1.1.zip
```

I would like to find all these files dynamically and copy them to a directory. I have tried the below command but it copies only last file(jenk*.zip) only, need a command which copies all the above files to a directory mentioned (test_dir);

```
find / -type f -name "*abc*.zip" -o -name "*kncb*.zip" -o -name "*jenk*.zip" ! -path '*/test_dir/*.jar' -exec cp -ar {} ./test_dir \;
```

Comment: are you guaranteed that there'll only be one of each of those?

Comment: why are you recursively copying (`-r`) when you're looking (presumably) for single files?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `( )` around your OR construct.

An explanation can be found in the man page:

> Please note that -a, when specified implicitly (for example by two
>   tests appearing without an explicit operator between them) or
>   explicitly, has higher precedence than -o. This means that find . -name
>   afile -o -name bfile -print will never print afile.

Example:

```
touch afile bfile
```

Without `( )`:

```
find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print
./bfile
```

which has an implicit -a between `-name bfile` and `-print`:

```
find . -name afile -o -name bfile -a -print
./bfile
```

With `( )` the result is as expected:

```
find . \( -name afile -o -name bfile \) -print
./afile
./bfile
```

Your implicit `-a` lies between `-o -name "*jenk*.zip"` and `! -path '*/test_dir/*.jar'`.

Comment: Getting an error when I run this from jenkins;                                                                                                           
find /  \(-name "*abc*.zip" -o -name "*kncb*.zip" -o -name "*jenk*.zip" \) ! -path '*/test_dir/*.jar' -exec cp -ar {} ./test_dir \;
find: invalid expression; you have used a binary operator '-o' with nothing before it.